# Is work done by gravity equal to zero in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, work, geodesics

I've heard it said that, according to Einstein's equations, gravity isn't actually a force but is instead an effect of the curvature of spacetime. In other words, a body in a gravitational field follows its geodesic without the need for a force dragging it along.

Given that work done on a body equals zero when either the displacement or net force on the body is zero, this non-force view of gravity implies work done by gravity is also (technically) zero.

I don't see any practical reason to treat gravitational work this way, but I'm curious definitionally.

Comment: "Force" and "Work" are really only concepts that have meaning in Newtonian physics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> gravity isn't actually a force ... I'm curious definitionally.

Ok, so “isn’t actually a force” is more of a pop-sci summary than something definitionally correct in General Relativity.

In Newtonian mechanics the gravitational force is mediated by the gravitational field which gives the gravitational acceleration at each event.

In general relativity the mathematical quantity that gives the gravitational acceleration at each event is the Christoffel symbols. This is the same quantity that produces inertial forces (also known as fictitious forces) like the centrifugal force and the Coriolis force.

This makes some sense because gravity, like all inertial forces, cannot be detected by an accelerometer, is always proportional to the mass, and can be made to appear or disappear through a change of coordinates. However, gravity is somewhat different because when spacetime is curved there is no coordinate system that can make gravity disappear everywhere.

Because the force of gravity is like an inertial force, some people will describe it as not actually a force at all. Such people typically dismiss all inertial forces as not being forces, and in particular the centrifugal force is often described as not a force. However, in the coordinates where an inertial force exists it does work, produces acceleration, and (depending on the details) can have an associated potential energy. So in coordinates where the force of gravity exists, it does work just like any inertial force

Comment: I strongly disagree with your assessment that the distinction is a pop-sci summary rather than definitionally true in GR. In the model, there is no invariant sense in which the trajectory of a test mass under the influence of only gravity is accelerating. These trajectories are explicitly defined in GR as non-accelerating curves, using the only invariant notion of acceleration available. They are the closest thing to a straight line achievable on a curved manifold.

Comment: @jawheele while you are certainly free to disagree, I stand by my statement. The actual math is more nuanced than the simple statement "gravity isn't actually a force" can convey. So I am comfortable calling that un-nuanced statement a pop-sci summary. You won't see such a statement in a standard GR textbook without several paragraphs or pages of support to convey the nuances. I tried to provide a taste of that here.

Comment: While I agree that the technicalities wrapped up in the statement are not well-communicated by it to a layperson in isolation, I think it contains the nuances as well as any single sentence can. I mean this in the sense that even once one had fully explained the mathematical intent and content, I'd reiterate precisely the same sentence as encapsulating the conclusion, with none of the new jargon needed to clarify or make it technically accurate. To my mind (as a GR theorist), that statement alone contains nearly all of the fundamental content of GR as it differs from SR.

Comment: @jawheele. In [Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) the equation of motion reads
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_i} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i}.$$
The right hand side is the Lagrangian definition of a (generalized) force, and that can vanish in one choice of coordinates and not in another.

Comment: @md2perpe And in [relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force) (clearly the appropriate context), the natural notion of force, the covariant derivative of momentum with respect to proper time, is a four vector that transforms between coordinate systems like any other tangent vector, and it will vanish in all coordinate systems if it vanishes in one.

Comment: @jawheele. How do you define momentum?

Comment: @md2perpe The object's 4-momentum tangent vector. That is, its velocity tangent 4-vector multiplied by mass. One can derive the geodesic equation from an action principle, wherein this agrees (perhaps up to a dualization) with the "generalized momentum". The difference between the relativistic notion of force and the "generalized force" of the action description is a covariant versus coordinate time derivative. So one can be said to be intrinsically associated to the manifold while the other cannot. The geodesic equation is the statement that the momentum's covariant time derivative is zero.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that the Christoffel symbols give rise to inertial forces or should be interpreted as their cause. Stick to Minkowski flat space time. Pick an inertial frame. Now just change coordinates ( non linearly) to polar coordinates. You are sticking in the same inertial frame just changing from Cartesian to polar coordinates not going in a rotating frame. There won’t be any fictitious forces yet the Christoffel symbols will not vanish.....Let me know if you do not agree...

Comment: @Shashaank I do not agree. The Lagrangian of a free particle in non-rotating polar coordinates is $L=(m/2)(\dot r^2+r^2\dot \theta^2)$ which leads to the generalized force $m r \dot \theta^2$. This force is a generalized force but it is not a real force, so I think it is completely legitimate to call it a fictitious force. It has all the usual characteristics of any other inertial force. Anyway, I didn't say all Christoffel symbols are inertial forces. I said they are what "produces inertial forces", which is accurate even if you disagree with labeling a specific symbol as an inertial force.

Comment: @Dale I think the correct expression for the generalised force will be $mr^2\dot{\dot{\theta}+2mr\dot{r}\dot{\theta}$ which is just the torque and torque is not a fictitious force. Anyways from Lagrangian or Newton’s eqn you get the theta component of the force which is **totally** real. There is no fictitious force there. The above written Lagrangian is by assumption written in inertial frame. If you need to get fictitious forces in the Lagrangian the R.H.S of Euler Lagrange eqn won’t be 0 and in that case you would have a generalised fictitious force but your frame is not inertial.

Comment: @Shashaank $\partial L/\partial r = m r \dot \theta^2$. Also, this is a free particle so if you do find a torque then that is indeed fictitious. In any case, even if you disagree with labeling a specific term as an inertial force the fact remains that anything that you **do** label as an inertial force does come from a Christoffel symbol. That is all I claimed in my answer

Comment: @Dale I agree with you that a fictitious force is indeed present, but in what sense does it do "work", as you've claimed? The force is radial and equal to $m \ddot r$, so it seems the best one can say, even in this simplest of transformations, is $\vec F \cdot \vec v = m \dot r \ddot r = \frac{d}{dt} (m \dot{r}^2/2)$, so this "work"-like quantity does not at all describe the change in total kinetic energy. The whole reason we define work is its relation to energy. Is your point only that quantities that look like work will be nonzero, regardless of whether their physical meaning is preserved?

Comment: @jawheele for a free particle in polar coordinates $L=T= (m/2)(\dot r^2+r^2 \dot \theta^2)$ so the generalized force is $F=\partial L/\partial r = mr \dot \theta^2$. This force leads to a power $F \dot r = m r \dot r \dot \theta^2$. This is exactly the first term in $dT/dt = m r \dot r \dot \theta^2+m \dot r \ddot r + m r^2 \dot \theta \ddot \theta$ so indeed it does work that is directly related to the change in KE.

Comment: @Dale Right, it is exactly the first term, which is generally nonzero. For a free particle, the change in kinetic energy is zero,  $\frac{dT}{dt} = 0$. The other terms exactly cancel this out. Your "work", the first term, gives no indication that the kinetic energy is constant.

Comment: @jawheele it is also completely valid to call $m r \dot r \dot \theta^2$ a (velocity dependent) potential energy in the non-inertial frame and to call the remaining terms the kinetic energy in the non-inertial frame. When we speak about work done by gravity in freshman physics, that is exactly what is done.

Comment: @Dale The units of your expression aren't energy. The equation of motion indicates that $F = m \ddot r$ and hence that the "power" is $F \dot r = \frac{d}{dt} (m\dot r^2/2)$, so you probably want your "potential" to be $m\dot r^2/2$. Either way, though, that is not at all what is done in the case of gravity. The kinetic energy discussed in Newtonian or SR limits is exactly that as measured by the family of observers encoded in the coordinates. One doesn't siphon off part of the kinetic energy expression and call it a potential by fiat to make things work out.

Comment: @Dale If it's not clear, the kinetic energy measured by the family of coordinate observers is the time component of the object's four-momentum vector according to the coordinates, less $mc^2$. There is no freedom there in what's being called kinetic energy-- it is imposed by the metric. And in our polar coordinates, this quantity is $T = (m/2)(\dot r^2 + (r \dot \theta)^2)$ (in our Newtonian limit of low speeds).

Comment: @jawheele oops you are right, that is a power, not an energy. Anyway, the polar coordinates is besides the point. I will tell you what I told Shashaank: even if you disagree with labeling a specific term as an inertial force the fact remains that anything that you do label as an inertial force does come from a Christoffel symbol. That is all I claimed in my answer, and that is correct. Those inertial forces can do work and can be associated with a potential. Anyway, as we are getting the "move to chat" warning I am done discussing. You are free to downvote the answer, I am comfortable with it.

Comment: @Dale I have no issue with what you called inertial forces-- I only took issue with the general claim that they do work in a meaningful sense, which was the point of OP's question. There are definitely specific cases in which these notions work nicely (specifically SR/Newtonian limits), so I don't feel the need to downvote, but this is also by no means generally true in GR at large, so I felt it worth clarifying. Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 4):

When discussing things in general relativity, one generally strives to describe physical phenomena in a way independent of arbitrary coordinate choices, so that one can be sure they're extracting real physical information about the model rather than coordinate artifacts. Forces on point masses can be described in a relativistic setting in keeping with this philosophy through the concept of [four-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force), the covariant derivative along the mass $m$'s trajectory of its four-momentum $P^\mu = m U^\mu$, where $U^\mu$ is its four-velocity:

$$ f^\mu = U^\nu \nabla_\nu P^\mu.$$

Covariant descriptions of classical electromagnetism [describe the Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Lorentz_force_in_general_relativity) on a charged particle as a four-force, for example:

$$f^\mu_\text{Lorentz} = q F^{\mu \nu}U_\nu,$$

where $F^{\mu \nu}$ is the electromagnetic tensor and $q$ the particle's charge. The magnitude of the net four-force [is physical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration) in the sense that it is the force the particle "feels" in its rest frame, i.e. its rest mass times its acceleration according to a momentarily co-moving inertial observer.

In general relativity, it is posited that test masses under the influence of gravity alone follow geodesics, for which the equation of motion is

$$ U^\nu \nabla_\nu U^\mu = 0.$$

Up to a factor of the constant mass, this is the statement that the covariant derivative of the particle's four-momentum is zero along its trajectory, i.e. that the net four-force is zero. This is what is meant when people say "gravity is not actually a force"-- the action of gravity alone is that of zero four-force. Though test particles following this motion can be said to have varying coordinate accelerations in different coordinate systems, they are *not* accelerating in the only invariant sense of acceleration available. They are following the straightest possible paths through the curved spacetime manifold.

So, what about work? Can we achieve a similarly natural relativistically invariant analog? Well, in a sense, though the concept doesn't seem to be discussed or utilized very much. Let's relax the assumption that our particle has constant mass, and recall that the four-velocity is the tangent vector to the trajectory when parameterized by proper time $\tau$, so that $U^\mu U_\mu = -1$ (I like signature $(- \, + \, + \, +)$ and units with $c = 1$), and we have
$$-2m \frac{dm}{d \tau} =\frac{d}{d \tau}( -m^2) = \frac{d}{d \tau} (P^\mu P_\mu) = U^\nu \nabla_\nu (P^\mu P_\mu) = 2 P^\mu U^\nu \nabla_\nu P_\mu = 2 P^\mu f_\mu$$

This then reads,

$$\frac{dm}{ d \tau} =  -U^\mu f_\mu.$$

The left hand side is the rate of change of the particle's rest mass with proper time, while the right hand side is what one would obtain by taking the Newtonian expression for work done per unit time (or power), $P = \vec F \cdot \vec v$ , and minimally substituting in the invariant relativistic analogs (the sign is an artifact of the signature-- if the vectors are parallel, the quantity is positive). This says something like "the relativistic work done by the net four-force is the change in rest mass". This might be what you'd guess, considering that the rest mass is the only coordinate-invariant measure of energy available (kinetic energy is right out, of course), and work is supposed to describe a change in energy.

In this sense, gravity of course does no work, as it contributes no four force. The Lorentz four force listed above also does no such work, since the tensor $F^{\mu \nu}$ is antisymmetric and hence $F^{\mu \nu} U_\mu U_\nu = 0$. This is saying, e.g., that electrons don't gain rest mass as they accelerate under the electromagnetic field.

That's the invariant discussion. Things get a lot hairier when attempting to use coordinate-dependent notions in GR. One can attempt to have this discussion in a coordinate-dependent way by considering the coordinate acceleration associated to geodesic motion, what one might call the acceleration due to gravity. In local inertial coordinates (i.e. a coordinate system "almost" special relativistic / Minkowski in a small region), at least, one can approximately recover the usual kinematic sense in which this coordinate acceleration does work in accordance with the work-energy theorem.

In a general coordinate system, though, there's not really a meaningful sense in which this is the case. There's difficulty defining what the terms should mean, so it depends on what you want to mean. When the coordinates are [structured well enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#General_relativity) that one can meaningfully consider a notion of coordinate kinetic energy, it will generally change under geodesic motion (so gravity does "work" in the sense that it impacts the coordinate kinetic energy), but it is not nicely related to any of the natural candidates for what one might mean by the coordinate force doing work as described through power: $\frac{d}{dt}(P^i)v^i$, $\frac{d}{d \tau}(P^i)v^i$, $\frac{d}{dt}(P^i)v^j g_{ij}$, $\frac{d}{dt}(g_{ij} P^i)v^j$, $m\frac{d}{dt}(v^i)v^i$, $m\frac{d}{dt}(v^i)v^j g_{ij}$, etc. (here $\vec v$ is the coordinate velocity and $P^\mu$ the four-momentum). In general, of course, there need not even be a nice break down into $3$ spatial coordinates and a time coordinate, so that none of the prior expressions even make sense. The best one can do with these expressions is say that, in coordinates where they make sense, these coordinate quantities that look like work are nonzero but have no consistent relation to actual energy.

What's the takeaway from all of that? It's that, yes, if you fully translate to the relativistic coordinate-invariant language in which gravity is not a force, gravity indeed does no work. However, work is typically not discussed in GR at all, so it's kind of a conceptual mismatch. The coordinate-invariant notion maybe isn't the most useful, and the coordinate-dependent notions either don't make sense or are, at best, strictly qualitative in their analog to the Newtonian situation. Only in special relativistic limits can one be sure the relations like the work-energy theorem are recovered, so that quantitative work of the kind that gravity would do as a coordinate force is really a special relativistic concept.